# how to Pass a JavaScript function name as parameter and replace function name like parameter

Tags: javascript, function

Its just an experiment

I can pass function name ass parameter but it's called the same name function.

```
function refreshContactList(id) {
    console.log(`Hello World ${id}`);
}

function addContact(id, refreshCallback) {
    refreshCallback(id);
}

addContact(1, refreshContactList);
```

like that.

---

but I want to change the function name, so its changes the name of the function
[like that ( image )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRyKq.png)

```
function addContact(id, refreshCallback) {
    
    function refreshCallback(id) {
        console.log(`Hello World ${id}`);
    }
    
}

addContact(1, refreshContactList);
```

is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: That does not make any sense. Why would you want to do that in the first place? Passing a function as argument to a function call enables the called function to call the passed function. When you define a function inside your main function, why would you want to use some passed name for that? Again, makes zero sense. Please tell us why you want to do this or what you think is accomplished by that, or which problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Also, in case this isn't clear: in your first snippet, you can also use `function addContact(id, bananas) { bananas(id); }` and will work the same way. Because that's how parameters in a function declaration work: they allow you to access what was passed as arguments to the function call. Their name is arbitrary, only the order matters.

Comment: @ChrisG
 actually, I want to make recallable functions like mongodb ( collection.updateOne().then(); ) have async functions but I don't want to rewrite this function again and again I just want to change function names like updateOne or deleteOne.

Comment: @ChrisG its just an experiment

Comment: That's not how this works. You need to write classes. These have methods and can return objects (which are also instances of classes with methods). This is what allows you to chain function calls like that. You are on the wrong track entirely.

Answer (score 0):

In your picture, you pass not name of function but the reference to this function.
If you really want to call the top-level function by the given name (that is, by the string with the name of this function), you can use a cross-platform method that works equally well in node.js, browsers (traditionally, except for Internet Explorer) and other platforms:
[globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis):

```
function a() {
  console.log('a')
}

function b() {
  console.log('b')
}

function callByName(name) {
  globalThis[name]
}

callByName(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is Nested Functions you want?

```
function addContact(id) {
    function anotherThing() {
        console.log(`Hello World ${id}`);
    }
    
    return { anotherThing };

}

addContact(1).anotherThing();
```